# Best effective SQL update on one to many relationship

Tags: sql, db2

I have one to many relationship tables

(one)table_one.OLD_ID ==> (many)table_two.OLD_ID:

table_one:

```
 OLD_ID    SOME_DATA     NEW_ID(ID)
"aaaaaa"    "dataA"       123
"bbbbbb"    "dataB"       124
```

table_two:

```
  OLD_ID  res_id(ID)  SOME_DATA     TABLE_ONE_NEW_ID
 "bbbbbb"   1          "DATA_Z"        NULL
 "aaaaaa"   2          "DATA_G"        NULL
 "aaaaaa"   3          "DATA_J"        NULL
 "aaaaaa"   4          "DATA_H"        NULL
 "bbbbbb"   5          "DATA_J"        NULL
```

Now I have almost 1,000,000 records from table_two
and almost 240,000 records from table_one.

What I'm trying to find is the fastest way to update table_two.TABLE_ONE_NEW_ID with table_one.NEW_ID by OLD_ID

This query is taking too much time:

```
UPDATE table_two
   set TABLE_ONE_NEW_ID = (select NEW_ID from table_one
                           where table_one.OLD_ID = table_two.OLD_ID)
```

I have indexes on:

table_two.OLD_ID, table_one.OLD_ID, table_one.NEW_ID

I'm using DB2 database.

Comment: Do you have an index on `table_one.Old_Id`?

Comment: Co-related queries are expensive in most of the cases.

Comment: yes i have index on table_one.Old_Id for now for now it's unique but after the update it will not.

Comment: I don't see how your update would affect the uniqueness of anything in `table_one`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume LUW here, I also assume there is a unique index on table_one (OLD_ID). Unless already so you might consider including new_id in such index, i.e.

```
create unique index ... on table_one (old_id) include (new_id) ...
```

It is probably easiest to do this with a merge statement:

```
merge into table_two x
using (
    select old_id, new_id from table_one
) y
    on x.old_id = y.old_id
when matched then update
    set x.TABLE_ONE_NEW_ID = y.new_id
```

For tables of the size you are referring to this may take a considerably amount of resources. It may be faster to export the data that is supposed to go into the table, and then replace the content in the table with that:

```
export to myfile.ixf of ixf
select x.old, x.res_id, x.some_data, y.new_id
from table_two x 
left join table_one y
    on x.old_id = y.old_id;

load from myfile.ixf of ixf replace into table_two [recoverable options]
```

See:

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.dm.doc/doc/t0004554.html

and:

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.dm.doc/doc/c0004587.html

Comment: whit the export method its take me only 18 sec to export and 106 sec to load it back! just great! it's important to use IXF and not DEL format

Answer (score 1):

If an index doesn't help, you may find that recreating the table is faster than doing an update.  After all updating all the rows in a table is a lot of work.

```
create table tmp_table2 like table_two;

insert into tmp_table2(OLD_ID, res_id, SOME_DATA, TABLE_ONE_NEW_ID)
    select t2.OLD_ID, t2.res_id, t2.SOME_DATA, t1.new_id
    from table_two t2 left join
         table_one t1
         on t2.old_id = t1.old_id;
```

This query will work best with an index on `table_one(old_id)`.

If that is successful and does what you want, then do:

```
truncate table table_two;

insert into table_two
    select *
    from tmp_table2;
```

Do validate the data before deleting everything, though.

Comment: with this qurey its was great imporove it's take me 6 minute but with the export method like Lennart suggest it take only 2 minute

Comment: @user986474 . . . Very interesting.  I'm surprised that exporting and re-importing the data is so much faster than creating a table and re-inserting the results.

Comment: @Gordon, the load utility writes formatted pages directly into the database and there is no overhead from logging etc. The downside is of course that it is not under transaction control. Since it does not write any transaction logs special actions have to be taken if the db belongs to a high availability cluster (HADR). There's a lot more to it, but that explains the improvement in speed over insert. These days one don't have to export to file, but can load from a cursor (not applicable here though since source and target is the same)